# boot-repair unallocated a secondary internal drive

Tags: boot-repair, restore, unallocated

Ok I had some boot issues which I managed to solved by reinstalling ubuntu on my primary disk (sda) before reaching to that point I used a program called boot repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Which didnt fix my problem in fact it made it worse (prior of using boot repair I could choose from grub the linux kernel and boot but I just couldnt log into my account because it was accepting it and throwing me again on the login screen after blacking out for a second anyway) after using bootrepair I couldnt even see grub... my computer looped in loading the bios screen and then restarting..

Boot repair did an other thing that I noticed only after I reinstalled ubuntu on my primary disk SDA.

I had a secondary disk (sdb) which had a windows installation (which I dont care if I can save or not) but also had a lot of personal data and documents!!! and it doesnt appear on ubuntu at all... using gparted I see that SDB has a red exclamation point and the entire disk is labeled as unallocated space!!!! (500GB of it)

I am 100% I never saw a formating process happening in the console nor did I see on any part of bootrepairs process SDB being mentioned! (It only purged and reinstalled kernel and grub on SDA!)

I could remove it from my computer and try to use a usb external drive hub to test if i can see its contents but before I go to such trouble is there anything else I can do?

I suspect that the data is intact and only some messy stuff happened to a few bits in the hard drives flag...

Please help the content of that drive is important to me.

Comment: What happens at the "login screen" has nothing to do with Grub. Boot Repair isn't applicable. Were you able to boot Windows before? Try booting from that drive, disable or disconnect others. Also UEFI or Legacy/CSM?

Comment: I dont follow you... I just mentioned the circumstances of why I used boot-repair to provide context on what happened and the status of my physical secondary data hard disk changed as "unallocated space" ubuntu is fixed now everything works my hard drive just doesnt get mounted because ubuntu thinks its "unallocated space" thats the problem I am trying to address here.

Comment: Oh now I get it... :P no I cant boot to windows. I think its UEFI although from gpart the flag of the sda1 is bios_grub which I think means its efi... SDa and SDb are two seperate physcal hard drives though so why does it matter what SDa is? SDB is to be used just as a data disk I dont care about saving its windows installation I just want to access the files pictures etc

Comment: That Red error is not from Boot-Repair, but usually from leaving Windows fast start up on or always on hibernation. You need to turn that off. And Windows updates may turn that back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If UEFI you can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. But if BIOS you may have to reinstall a Windows boot loader to sdb. BIOS boot  fixes: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: Its bios.. so the only way to access those files is by reinstalling windows? I just want the disk not to appear as "unallocated" space and get mounted by ubuntu and have access to my documents videos and pictures stored there.